# Show that Restricted Isometry property implies Restricted nullspace property

Tags: matrices, information-theory, sparse-matrices, compression

I need to show that if matrix A satisfies the RIP then it also satisfies the RNP.
I need to prove that each of the lemmas holds and then show that RIP implies RNP using the lemmas.

> **Lemma 1:** Let the vector  have  nonzero entries. Then
> $$
> \|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{s} \|x\|_2
> $$
> where x is an s-sparse vector.

> **Lemma 2:** Let $u,v$ be $s$-sparse vectors. If $\operatorname{supp}(u) \cap \operatorname{supp}(v) = \emptyset$, then
> $$
> \frac 1m |\langle Au, Av| \leq \delta_{2s}\|u\|_2\|v\|_2
> $$
> where $\delta_{2s}$ denotes the constant assocaited with the RIP of order $2s$.

What I've managed:
$\frac{1}{m}|⟨, ⟩| = \frac{1}{m}|v^T A^T A u|$
$= |v^T \frac{1}{m}A^T A u| = |v^T (\frac{1}{m}A^T A - I)u|$

Alternative method:
$\frac{1}{m}|⟨, ⟩| = \frac{1}{m}|⟨, ⟩ - ⟨, ⟩| $
But I don't fully understand how that part is explained.
Could someone show how it's done?

> **Lemma 3:** Let $a,b$ be two $s$-dimensional vectors such that the largest entry in the absolute value of $b$ is no larger than the smallest entry in the absolute value of $a$. Then
> $$
> \|a\|_1 \geq \sqrt{s} \|b\|_2
> $$

I especially need help proving the lemmas.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please use mathjax for better readability. It's not clear what Lemma 2 really says. (Lemma 1 is a standard application of Cauchy Schwarz). also please state what progress you have made and where this problem is coming from. *It seems to be a class project in compressed sensing.*

Comment: @HansEngler Hey! I've managed to solve the first lemma with l1-norm with a vector with ones. Then taking the chauchy-schwartz inequality. For lemma two I've manged to do : $\frac{1}{m} * |{<Au,Av>}| = \frac{1}{m}|{v^T A^T A u}|$                                         Though I've found a solution which states: $\frac{1}{m} * |{<Au,Av>}|  =   \frac{1}{m} * |{<Au,Av>} - <u,v>|$ but I don't know how to derive this statement. Could you show me how?